# Linux Shared Memory Synchronization

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory, performance

I have implemented two applications that share data using the POSIX shared memory API (i.e. `shm_open`). One process updates data stored in the shared memory segment and another process reads it. I want to synchronize the access to the shared memory region using some sort of mutex or semaphore. What is the most efficient way of do this? Some mechanisms I am considering are

- A POSIX mutex stored in the shared memory segment (Setting the PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED attribute would be required)
- Creating a System V semaphore using `semget`

Comment: What programming language ? For C++ consider `boost::interprocess`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a shared memory segment instead of a named file on a `tmpfs` or `hugetlbfs`?  I'd probably use a POSIX mutex since they've been very fast for several years on Linux.

Comment: @tmyklebu: I am using shared memory to avoid system calls and unnecessary data copying. After the shared memory segments are setup, the data is accessed by simply using pointers.

Comment: What unnecessary data copying happens when you create, grow, and `mmap()` a file on a `tmpfs` or `hugetlbfs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than a System V semaphore, I would go with a POSIX named semaphore using `sem_open()`, etc.

Comment: Does POSIX guarantee that such semaphores may be shared between processes?  (Seems logical, but I cannot find the wording.)  `sem_init` (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_init.html) with `pshared` true would definitely work for this application, since he already has the shared memory segment.

Comment: Using the POSIX semaphore added no noticeable overhead and API is very straightforward.

Comment: Be carefull though, semaphores are an optional feature in POSIX. In addition there are nasty implementations that "implement" `sem_init` by just always setting an error code. AFAIR OSX is one such system.

Answer (score 2):

Might as well make this an answer.

You can use [sem_init](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_init.html) with `pshared` true to create a POSIX semaphore in your shared memory space.  I have used this successfully in the past.

As for whether this is faster or slower than a shared mutex and condition variable, only profiling can tell you.  On Linux I suspect they are all pretty similar since they rely on the "futex" machinery.

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is important, I would go with process-shared mutexes and condition variables.

AFAIR, each operation with a semaphore requires a syscall, so uncontended mutex should be faster than the semaphore [ab]used in mutex-like manner.

Comment: Typically `sem_post` should just be an atomic increment and not result in a syscall.

Answer (score 0):

First, really benchmark to know if performance is important. The cost of these things is often overestimated. So if you don't find that the access to the control structure is of same order of magnitude than the writes, just take whatever construct is semantically the best for your use case. This would be the case usually if you'd have some 100 bytes written per access to the control structure.

Otherwise, if the control structure is the bottleneck, you should perhaps avoid to use them. C11 has the new concept of `_Atomic` types and operations that can be used in cases where there are races in access to data. C11 is not yet widely implemented but probably all modern compilers have extensions that implement these features already.

Comment: Do the standard C11 and C++11 synchronization mechanisms work across processes?  (Do the standards even have a concept of "across processes"?)

Comment: No, they, don't have a concept of shared memory. Nevertheless the underlying processor features that all modern processors have to provide this feature should be completely agnostic about this question. They act directly on the memory that is presented to them.

Comment: There is no guarantee the standard mechanisms will synchronize correctly between processes.  For example, a multi-threaded environment might use a userspace threading library with no kernel support for pre-emption. In that case, the synchronization primitives might not bother synchronizing memory with appropriate barriers. (Unlikely?  Sure.  But definitely permitted by the standard, making this a poor answer to the question as phrased.)

Comment: I have difficulties to imagine how you may ensure proper synchronization of atomic operations between threads that would not do the same between processes. In any case you'd have a context switch to manage between the threads. But be it, you are right that POSIX has not yet have the time to react on C11. All previous versions of the C standard have always been "incorporated" by direct reference into POSIX. And the poor strategy is not my answer, but to always impose synchronization structures for parallel processing. Atomic operations are there in the CPUs since years, we should use them.

Comment: @Nemo also to come back to your "poor answer" statement. The accepted answer is not much better, because semaphores are optional POSIX features and even if they are implemented the specification is too weak that it enforces reasonable behavior.