# Atomic get and increment functionality on a value in shared memory, in Java

Tags: java, shared-memory, increment, atomic

I have several processes (on the same computer) which together need to sequentially access the elements of an array in shared memory. To do this I want to store the current index into the array as an int in shared memory, and for each of the processes to be able to get the current value of the index and increment it by a fixed value in one single atomic operation. How can I do this in Java?

Note: I only want this atomic operation coded in Java. The rest of the code happens to be in MATLAB.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show what you have tried already?

Comment: what if you synchronize the part that access the shared memory from java ?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I have not tried coding anything yet. I have searched online using suitable terms, but nothing helpful came up. The links found (e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html ) don't mention shared memory or get and increment as a single atomic operation.

Comment: @user664303: it's fairly hard to believe that something as simple as keeping an `int` concurrent hasn't been asked yet. I suggest you search for references and edit your post to clarify how the proposed solutions don't apply to your situation. This will get people to be more willing to help.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: Use a mutex? Sounds sensible. How do I create a mutex that can be seen by different processes (i.e. different programs)?

Comment: either implement a centralized service that reads / writes to shared memory and do synchronization there or else go for a flag based approach

Comment: why not use threads instead of processes?

Comment: @no_answer_not_upvoted: Because the environment I'm working in (MATLAB) doesn't allow me to create threads. I have to instantiate whole new instances of the environment.

Comment: This is interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3194284/664303 . Is it not possible to cast some sensibly initialized shared memory to a Java mutex object?

Comment: An `AtomicInteger` is typically used from within the same process, not across processes. Moreover, what if the java process dies? As other suggester, I recommend using a database, __not__ in memory. You can use any open source DB such as Postgres or MySQL. You just need a table that acts as a lock and read/update it within one single transaction locking the whole row/table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the file system: [Getting exclusive system-wide lock in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194227/getting-exclusive-system-wide-lock-in-java)

Or if you can use C instead, then you can create a POSIX mutex in shared memory: [Linux Shared Memory Synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364253/linux-shared-memory-synchronization)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what you're trying to do is kinda necessary.  However, just taking a swing at it - you'll probably want some kind of in-memory database.

The oracle led me here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-shared-memory-java, but there's also things like h2 (http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), which I've used before to good effect.

Let us know what you're trying to accomplish and we can probably help more.

Comment: Updated the question. I only need the atomic get and increment functionality, or even just a mutex in shared memory, so an entire in-memory database seems overkill.

Comment: Use a database but not in memory. You want to maintain the state of your lock indefinitely as far as I understand.